# call/cc in Python — Possible?

Tags: python, continuations, callcc

Say, we have the following code in Scheme

```
(define cc #f)
(define bar 0)

(define (func)
  (print "This should show only once")
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cc k)))
  (print bar)
  (set! bar (+ bar 1)))

(define (g)
  (func)
  (print "This should show multiple times"))

(g)
(cc)
```

which prints something like

```
This should show only once
0
This should show multiple times
1
This should show multiple times
```

And suppose we want to do the same in Python. http://wiki.c2.com/?ContinuationsInPython this approach doesn't work, because they save only the code and not the stack. I've tried to implement my version of `call/cc` in Python, saving and restoring the stack context. I'm not 100% sure that I've implemented continuations logics correctly, but this is not important now.

My idea is to save stack and instruction pointers of the function invoking `callcc` and its callers in `Continuation` constructor and then, in continuation's `__call__` method, reset the instruction pointers in the saved stack frames, point the current stack frame `f_back` pointer to the saved stack frame and return to magically appear in the function which called `callcc`.

The problem is that even though the output of the `traceback.print_stack()` shows that the current stack has been replaced, the code is still executes as if I haven't touched the current stack at all. Here is my implementation https://ideone.com/kGchEm

```
import inspect
import types
import ctypes
import sys
import traceback


frameobject_fields = [
    # PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    ("ob_refcnt", ctypes.c_int64),
    ("ob_type", ctypes.py_object),
    ("ob_size", ctypes.c_ssize_t),
    # struct _frame *f_back;      /* previous frame, or NULL */
    ("f_back", ctypes.c_void_p),
    # PyCodeObject *f_code;       /* code segment */
    ("f_code", ctypes.c_void_p),
    # PyObject *f_builtins;       /* builtin symbol table (PyDictObject) */
    ("f_builtins", ctypes.py_object),
    # PyObject *f_globals;        /* global symbol table (PyDictObject) */
    ("f_globals", ctypes.py_object),
    ####
    ("f_locals", ctypes.py_object),
    ("f_valuestack", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)),
    ("f_stacktop", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)),
    ("f_trace", ctypes.py_object),
    ("f_exc_type", ctypes.py_object),
    ("f_exc_value", ctypes.py_object),
    ("f_exc_traceback", ctypes.py_object),
    ("f_tstate", ctypes.c_void_p),
    ("f_lasti", ctypes.c_int),
]
if hasattr(sys, "getobjects"):
    # This python was compiled with debugging enabled.
    frameobject_fields = [
        ("_ob_next", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("_ob_prev", ctypes.c_void_p),
    ] + frameobject_fields
class PyFrameObject(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = frameobject_fields


class Continuation:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        self.lasti = frame.f_lasti
        self.lastis = []

        frame = frame.f_back
        while frame is not None:
            self.lastis.append(frame.f_lasti)
            frame = frame.f_back

    def __call__(self):
        print('\nbefore')
        traceback.print_stack()

        cur_frame = PyFrameObject.from_address(id(inspect.currentframe()))
        PyFrameObject.from_address(cur_frame.f_back).ob_refcnt -= 1
        cur_frame.f_back = id(self.frame)
        PyFrameObject.from_address(id(self.frame)).ob_refcnt += 1

        frame = self.frame
        _frame = PyFrameObject.from_address(id(frame))
        _frame.f_lasti = self.lasti + 4

        frame = frame.f_back
        for lasti in self.lastis:
            if len(frame.f_code.co_code) != frame.f_lasti + 2:
                break
            _frame = PyFrameObject.from_address(id(frame))
            _frame.f_lasti = lasti + 4
            frame = frame.f_back

        print('\nafter')
        traceback.print_stack()


def callcc(f):
    f(Continuation(inspect.currentframe().f_back))


cc = None


def func():
    bar = 0
    print("This should show only once")
    def save_cont(k):
        global cc
        cc = k
    callcc(save_cont)
    print(bar)
    bar += 1


def g():
    func()
    print("This should show multiple times")

sys.stderr = sys.stdout
g()
cc()
```

Comment: isn't a generator an abstract type of continuation? It nominally tracks/saves the state of the stack after each yield...

Comment: @cowbert man, if I wanted to use `yield`, I would have used `yield`.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand _why_ you want to do this, and not use a generator.  With as little offence as possible, you're writing terrible Python.  A resumable function is a generator is a resumable function.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: But again, _why_?  "The whole stack" is something you should _never_ be thinking about in Python.  It's an implementation detail that is purposefully out of reach.

Comment: @AdamBarnes call/cc is more general than generator. For example, how do you implement [amb operator](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Amb)

Comment: @Akangka imperatively.  This is Python.  We write simple clear code, not magic that makes us feel incredibly clever.

Comment: @AdamBarnes "We write simple clear code" Simple clear code is in the eye of the beholder. For example, writing a C code and linking to Python via FFI may disqualify, and yet It's important for the implementation of a library like NumPy. Call/cc is not something you use to make an application. However, it's important for building a continuation-based web framework, for example.

Comment: A widely used, successful, Pythonic web framework is Django.  I write code like Django's source every day I'm at work.  I look at Django's source about as much as I look at its documentation.  I am not fired for writing unreadable "look how clever I am" code such as what appears in the OP.  It follows that there may be some connection between that, and the lack of a "continuation-based web framework" competitor to Django.

Comment: As Akangka pointed out, continuations can be used for many purposes such as implementing backtracking, a web-server or multitasking. They are also a useful device for doing programming language research.

Comment: People write code for various reasons such as exploring what a computer (and/or) language can do for them. Not all programming is required to have a useful outcome or even a specific goal. I highly recommend that you try [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/) if you haven't done so. It will broaden your horizon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the standard interpreter — CPython — is a stackful interpreter, i.e. every invocation of Python function results in recursive call inside the interpreter. So the Python `FrameType` objects are just *views* (`.f_back` is a read-only attribute for the good reason) of the C stack frames, there is no point to change the `f_back` pointer.

If you really want to manipulate the stack, you will have to write a C module, like the [greenlet](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/blob/master/greenlet.c) module does.

Goog luck!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346433/in-c-python-accessing-the-bytecode-evaluation-stack) does a great job of explaining why it's hard to capture the state of the Python interpreter. [This package](https://github.com/a-rahimi/python-checkpointing2) does it for you. It doesn't implement call/cc, but it does implement longjmp and setjmp, which is just some syntactic sugar away from call/cc.